# Git Resolve Conflict Extra File

Tags: git, github, version-control, tortoisegit

I often comes under situation where I face issues in resolving conflicts.

- Lets in my PR (Feature -> Develop) I have conflict in 2 files.
- I run the command in my feature branch, `git pull origin develop`
- This sometimes add to many red,green etc files in my feature branch.
- I resolve the conflicts in 2 files.Then run
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m"resolved conflict"`
- `git push origin feature-branch`.
  Issue is : In diff tab, lots of files comes which are not related with my feature work.

How can I solve it?

Also I used Tortoise Git to solve this problem but didn't work :

- Once conflicts comes in my PR, I do the below steps.
- From my feature branch, git -> pull -> remote branch (develop)
- This also add plenty of unnecessary files.
- I resolve the conflicts.
- At time of commit, git ask to choose commit file, I select only two file and push.
- Even then, all files go to the remote/origin/feature-branch.
- This time prepare index takes too long, once push,its tough for reviewer.

Any solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Please narrow down your question to the exact step where the problem is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have the problem of extra files that comes when i take git pull from develop to resolve conflicts. And all these files later gets push on my feature branch which is difficult for reviewer to review

Comment: Then try to avoid having so many different files in your different branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How can I control files in other branches, devs create files as per their story :)

Comment: If new files are coming in, and they represent welcome changes to the codebase, then so be it.  In any case, they should not conflicting with your code because they were never part of your branch.

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, there have merge conflicts for a PR.

- **If you are only the developer to create PR to merge `feature` branch into `develop` branch**, it’s not necessary for you to resolve the potential merge conflicts. Resolving the merge conflicts is the business for the PR approvers/reviewers. They should resolve the conflicts when completing the PR.

  If you truly want to view/resolve the potential merge conflicts before creating a PR, you can use `git diff feature develop` to check the differences between the two branches. And then use `git checkout develop filename` to resolve the potential conflicts.

  Assume both `feature` and `develop` branch change the file `test.txt`, you can resolve the potential merge conflicts by keeping the file `test.txt` on `feature` branch as the same version on `develop` branch. you can use

  ```
  git checkout develop test.txt
  git commit -m 'change test.txt same as develop branch'
  ```

  Now the `test.txt` on `feature` branch is same as the version on `develop` branch. Then you can create a PR.
- **If you are not only the developer to create a PR, but also the approver to review and approval the PR**, you can resolve the merge conflicts on your local repo and then push the changes to `develop` branch directly.